# Set href string in angular 8 given by server

Tags: angular8

I have this in my html:

```
<a href="{{cookie_policy_url}}" target="_blank" class="primary">
```

where `cookie_policy_url` is a string that is initially blank and that I get from the server, this way:

```
 this.navService.getUrlCookiePolicy().subscribe(s => {
      this.cookie_policy_url = s;
      this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
    });
```

The string I receive is correct, but for some reasons it doesn't update the href url, so when I click it it is empty. What is the correct way to use this?

Comment: I tried your case and everything works fine. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jfb9ye

Comment: @jasonvuriker I've added async but it doesn't update the link

Comment: I think it worth observing your code once again